# Nightwatchjs DNS request custom commands

Tags: node.js, callback, dns, promise, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to make [DNS requests](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html) (resolve & reverse) and make assertions on results.

I run two **similar custom commands in a row**, both executing [dns.setServers()](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_setservers_servers) function to be able to **set a different DNS server** for each query.

I encountered this known issue :
`node: ../deps/cares/src/ares_destroy.c:102: ares__destroy_servers_state: Assertion ares__is_list_empty(&server->queries_to_server)' failed.`

Since it seems that it won't be resolved [nodejs#894](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/894) -> [c-ares#41](https://github.com/c-ares/c-ares/issues/41).

I'm looking for a solution, here is the code :

Custom command **dnsresolve** :

```
var util = require('util');
var events = require('events');
var dns = require ('dns');

var dnsresolve = function() {
  events.EventEmitter.call(this);
};

util.inherits(dnsresolve, events.EventEmitter);

dnsresolve.prototype.command = function(server, hostname, rrtype, callback) {
  var self = this;
  var server = server.split();

  dns.resolve(hostname, rrtype, function(err, result) {
    dns.setServers(server);
    if (result) {
      callback(result);
    } else {
      callback(err.code);
    }

    self.emit('complete');
  });

  return this;
};

module.exports = dnsresolve;
```

Custom command **dnsreverse**:

```
var util = require('util');
var events = require('events');
var dns = require ('dns');

var dnsreverse = function() {
  events.EventEmitter.call(this);
};

util.inherits(dnsreverse, events.EventEmitter);

dnsreverse.prototype.command = function(server, ip, callback) {
  var self = this;
  var server = server.split();

  dns.reverse(ip, function(err, result) {
    dns.setServers(server);
    if (result) {
      callback(result);
    } else {
      callback(err.code);
    }

    self.emit('complete');
  });

  return this;
};

module.exports = dnsreverse;
```

Custom commands calls :

```
'Browse' : function (browser) {
  browser
    .url('http://' + browser.globals.network.interfaces.em0.ip)
    .waitForElementVisible('#frameContent', 2000)
    .dnsresolve(browser.globals.network.interfaces.em0.ip, 'my.record', 'A', function(result) {
      browser.verify.equal(result, '1.1.1.1')
    })
    .dnsreverse(browser.globals.network.interfaces.em0.ip, '1.1.1.1', function(result) {
      browser.verify.equal(result, 'my.record')
    })
}
```

Using other node modules **is not** a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just made of those commands, some custom assertions:

```
module.exports = {
  'resolve' : function(browser, server, hostname, rrtype, expect) {
    browser
    .dnsresolve(server, hostname, rrtype, function(result) {
      browser.verify.equal(result, expect)
    }).pause(10)
  },
  'reverse' : function(browser, server, ip, expect) {
    browser
    .dnsreverse(server, ip, function(result) {
      browser.verify.equal(result, expect)
    }).pause(10)
  }
};
```

**Adding** '.pause(10)' is the **trick**, didn't find a proper way to do it.